# Why are these two strings not equal in Python?

Tags: python

I have a simple Python code sample

```
import json
hello = json.dumps("hello")
print(type(hello))

if hello == "hello":
    print("They are equal")
else:
    print("They are not equal")
```

This is evaluating to "They are not equal". I don't understand why these values are not equal.

I'm re-familiarizing myself with Python but I read that this "==" can be used as an [operator](https://www.journaldev.com/23511/python-string-comparison) to compare strings in Python. I also printed the type of hello which evaluates to "str"

Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior becomes much more clear once you print out the result from `json.dumps()`:

```py
print("hello", len("hello"))
print(hello, len(hello))
```

This outputs:

```
hello 5
"hello" 7
```

`json.dumps()` adds extra quotation marks -- you can see that the lengths of the two strings aren't the same. This is why your check fails.

Answer (score 1):

json.dumps is used to convert dictonaries to json strings.
In other words, it interprets the import and creates the equivalent of it as a json. What that means is, that puting a single string in will result in it being transformed to the json equivalent of a single string.

```
hello = json.dumps("hello")
print(hello)
 => "hello"
```

In the json-format, strings are in quotes, which is why json.dumps() puts it in quotes.

Answer (score -4):

```
print(json.dumps('hello'))
```

output -> `"hello"`

```
print('hello')
```

output -> `hello`

[image]